# Fullcalendar Event Drop in modal not working

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, event-drops

I have problem with editable fullcalendar eventdrop in modal dialog if another FullCalendar is in background. Modal with second calendar open after click on event in first calendar. But I need moving with event with calendar in modal view, but its not working when the first calendar is in background. Can you take me some solution? Its probably a css bug of FullCalendar.
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the problem in your question. Clearly we cannot fix pictures.  See also [ask]. Thanks

Comment: The problem is describe here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5026

Comment: Ok. But to be valid on Stackoverflow there must be enough information _within_ the question for it to be answerable based only on what is shown here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (item 1 in the numbered section)